# Desktop and app in Split View

Tags: desktop, split-view

In my office, I have an LG ultrawide display connected to my MBP (which is inside a Henge dock). The size of the display allows me to use multiple apps in Split View really well. I often use two Parallels VMs next to each other in this way, and that works really great.

This got me thinking, however: is there any way to use a desktop in Split View next to a VM?
I'm guessing there is no 'official' way to do so, but is there any way to get this done, or get something similar going?

To further clarify: 
What I'd like to achieve is this, but with my Mac desktop in stead of one of my VMs:

[image: Side by side Parallels VMs]

Comment: don't understand the question. When you say "desktop" do you mean a "desktop computer" like an iMac or Mac Pro? Or do you mean the folder /Users/<user>/Desktop which is initially visible when you log in and no windows or apps are open?

Comment: I mean the Mac desktop, with the menu bar and the Dock and multiple application windows.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is no, as the Desktop (with multiple windows, Dock, menu bar, etc.) is not a resizable window and so can't be split in the same way as other windows.

The best you can do is show the Desktop folder *as* a folder which can participate in the Split View.

Comment: I'm not especially interested in the desktop for the files that are on it, I'm interested in having two spaces next to each other where I move about application windows, as shown in the screen shot in my question. I could technically create a VM with macOS in it (from my recovery partition) but that seems a bit wasteful.